# What is the use case for having a default value for a required field in thrift?

Tags: thrift

I see that we can set default values for required fields in a thrift, something like

`required string xyz = ABC`

What is the use case of something like this?

In the case the writer doesn't want to pass a field, we have the `optional string xyz = ABC` which is much more intuitive. I read through the thrift documentation and several other sources, but could not quite figure out when we would be setting a default value for a required field.

Can someone pelase help me out here

Answer (score 0):

For optional field you can use `null` value instead of default, so you can override default value with `null`.

But for required field you cannot use `null` value and in this way you have guarantee that this field will be not empty but you can omit setting some value for this field, because it has default value.